# How to debug a hanging express server?

Tags: node.js, express

In the next example, the application is using a `m` middleware.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const m = () => (req, res, next) => {
  next();
};

app.use(m());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(5000);
```

if I (by accident) passed the function itself instead of the result of calling it:

```
-app.use(m()); 
+app.use(m); // causes express server hangs
```

the [express](/questions/tagged/express) server will hangs.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: I can't say how much I abhor this construct `const m = () => (req, res, next) => {...}`.  About as unreadable as they come without any purpose for actually using arrow functions except to obscure readability.  Also, there's NO reason for making a function that returns a function here either.  Just make a function and just pass the function reference as middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is a function that returns a middleware function when you call it.

To get the middleware function you have to call it with `m()`.  If you just pass `m`, then that's not a middleware function and executing it just immediately returns another function and never calls `next()` so when express executes `m`, it runs, immediately returns another function (which is ignored by Express) and your request is never handled.

---

Also, there's NO reason for making a function that returns a function in the case you show either. Just make a function and pass a reference to that function as middleware.

```
function m(req, res, next) {
    next();
}

app.use(m);
```

Or inline:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   next();
});
```

Comment: The code in my question is a toy example of the case of misusing a third-party middleware,  the core of my question is how to debug such cases.

Comment: @tarrsalah - Well, you can put a breakpoint or `console.log()` in both levels of your function and see what does or doesn't get called.  That would show you that the inner function is never called.  At that point, you probably need to study the code and deduce why it's not getting called.

Comment: @tarrsalah - It is possible to put breakpoints into the internals of express and step through it's routing mechanism, but it is particularly hard and it wouldn't really help you much with such a brief single line definition of `m` anyway because you couldn't really see what's going on even if you got to the breakpoint and went into `m`.  Better to just spread `m` out into multiple lines and instrument `m` or set breakpoints in `m` so you can see in the console what's going on when you do get in there.